# File nesting option missing in Service Fabric Stateless Service project type

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.2

In my Service Fabric API project I can access the file nesting option:
[image: Azure Service Fabric Web API]

However it's not available in my Azure Service Fabric Stateless Service project:
[image: Azure Service Fabric Stateless Service]

I saw that the API project has a file called `.filenesting.json` in the solution folder, so I tried adding this file to the Stateless Service solution folder, and restarted VS, however the option still was not there.

Here's the content of the `.filenesting.json` file:

```
{
    "help":"https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866610"
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.5.

How can I get file nesting to work in a Stateless Service project?

Comment: Is your stateless service project a .NET CORE project? I see in the help link you provided that is a limitation. Also, what exactly is the end goal here? What are you looking to accomplish with this nesting file? My assumption is it is not something available for SF clusters but want to understand your use case here

Comment: Yeah it's .net core 2.2. I want to be able to have all the appsettings.{environment}.json files nested under the appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing around.

Depending on the type of SF Project you create file nesting will be available or not.

For example, using .NET CORE stateless service and stateful services do not support file nesting 
[image]

But selecting Stateless or Stateful ASP.NET core app does support it
[image]

[image]